# Lex and Yacc decleared type, SYNTAX ERROR

Tags: token, union, flex-lexer, yacc, lex

in .y code:

```
 %union{
    int ival;
    int *ivals;
    char id[20];
    char *str;
    bool *b;
}
%start START

%token COMMENT OP_PLUS OP_MINUS OP_DIV OP_MULT OP_OP OP_CP OP_DBLMULT OP_OC OP_CC OP_COMMA KW_AND KW_OR KW_NOT KW_EQUAL KW_LESS
KW_NIL KW_LIST KW_APPEND KW_CONCAT KW_SET KW_DEFFUN KW_FOR KW_IF KW_EXIT KW_DEFVAR KW_WHILE
KW_LOAD KW_DISP KW_TRUE KW_FALSE NEWLINE
FLOAT_NUMBER LISTOP


%token <ival> LIMITED_VALUE
%token <id> IDENTIFIER
%token <str> FLE
%token <ival> NUMBER

%type <ival> START
%type <ival> EXPI
%type <ival> EXPB
%type <ivals> VALUES
%type <ivals> EXPLISTI
%type <ivals> LISTVALUE
%type <b> BinaryValue
```

in l code:

```
[[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]]*   {strcpy(yylval.id, yytext); return IDENTIFIER;}
[[1-9][:digit:]]+         {yylval.ival = atoi(yytext); return VALUE;}
{LIMITED_VALUE}                   {yylval.ival = atoi(yytext); return VALUE;}
```

I got an error:

error: $3 of ‘EXPI’ has no declared type
$$=$3;

code blog with the line where I got the error:

```
| OP_OP KW_WHILE OP_OP EXPB OP_CP EXPLISTI OP_CP{ 
    $$=$3; 
    if(!$3){
        listIndex=0;
        listValues[0]=NULL;
    }
    list_flag=1;
}
```

Why am I getting an error when I declare it? Can you help me solve this?

----Update---

I solved this problem with @sepp2k's answer, but now I am getting different error.

```
START:| INPUT{
        if(!flag && list_flag){
            printf("Syntax OK.\n");
            printf("Result:"); 
            
            printList(listValues,listIndex); 
            listIndex=0;
            
            holdIndex=0;
            list_flag=0;
        }
        else if(!flag && binary_flag){
            printf("Syntax OK.\n");
            if($$==1)
                printf("Result:T\n");
            else
                printf("Result:NIL\n");
            binary_flag=0;
        }
        else if(!flag){
            printf("Syntax OK.\n");
            printf("Result:%d",$$); 
        }
        return 0;
        };

INPUT: EXPI | EXPLISTI | EXPB{ binary_flag=1; }
;

EXPI: OP_OP KW_DEFVAR IDENTIFIER EXPI OP_CP { $$=$4; } 
| OP_OP KW_SET IDENTIFIER EXPI OP_CP { $$=$4; } 
| OP_OP OP_PLUS EXPI EXPI OP_CP { $$=$3+$4; } 
| OP_OP OP_MINUS EXPI EXPI OP_CP { $$=$3-$4; } 
| OP_OP OP_MULT EXPI EXPI OP_CP { $$=$3*$4; } 
| OP_OP OP_DBLMULT EXPI EXPI OP_CP { $$=pow($3,$4); } 
| OP_OP OP_DIV EXPI EXPI OP_CP { $$=$3/$4; }
```

This is in my .y code. If I wrote the (* 5 2) in consol I'm getting error which is SYNTAX_ERROR Expression not recognized. I have defined this syntax why am I getting such an error?

Comment: `$3` is `OP_OP`, which doesn't have a type. `EXPB` is `$4`.

Comment: @sepp2k thank you for answer, it works but now I'm getting an error on something else

Comment: @sepp2k I updated the question about the error I got, I would be very happy if you take a look again

Comment: General parser debugging -- use the `-d` option to bison and put in `yydebug = 1;` just before you call `yyparse()`.  For your code, it looks like you do not have anything to recognize a simple interger constant as an `EXPI`

Comment: I use -d option @ChrisDodd , before adding union (* 5 2) did not give any error. I do not understand what you said

Comment: The `-d` option allows setting the `yydebug` global variable to generate a trace of the parsing process (showing the tokens shifted and the rules reduced and the parsing stack along the way)

Comment: @ChrisDodd The debug flag is `-t` (t like "teabugging", I assume). `-d` generates the header file even if you didn't specify `%defines` in the grammar file.

Comment: @sepp2k: oops, yes, that right -- the correct argument is `-t` or `--debug`

Comment: @ChrisDodd  I tried to compile with -t and results:
  Starting parse
Entering state 0
Reading a token: >(* 5 2)
Next token is token OP_OP ()
Shifting token OP_OP ()
Entering state 2
Reading a token: Next token is token OP_MULT ()
Shifting token OP_MULT ()
Entering state 19
Reading a token: Next token is token LIMITED_VALUE ()

SYNTAX_ERROR Expression not recognized
Error: popping token OP_MULT ()
Stack now 0 2
Error: popping token OP_OP ()
Stack now 0
Cleanup: discarding lookahead token LIMITED_VALUE ()
Stack now 0
lala: syntax error

Comment: So that shows your problem -- there's no bison rule that can recognize a `LIMITED_VALUE` token here (the integer constant `5`).